# Pascal Triangle type Problem - Find the number in top layer by adding each pair of adjacent numbers in the lower layer

Tags: python, list, tuples

I don't even know how to start on this :( I'm supposed to create a function. The question is as follows:

> A pyramid of size n is formed with a base consisting of n numbers,
> given as a list
>
> Next layer contains (n-1) numbers, and following contains (n-2)
> numbers, etc. Each number is obtained from adding each pair of
> adjacent numbers in the lower layer and process is repeated until top
> layer has 1 number.
>
> Problem: Create a function that takes in a list of numbers in the
> bottom layer and returns the top layer

E.g.

```
    8
  5   3
3   2   1
```

test cases:

```
pyramid([1, 2])

3

pyramid([3, 2, 1])

8

pyramid([2, 0, 2, 1])

9
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I presume you know how to handle the first case, right? Think about how to take the second case and return an array that looks like the first case, and then use what you know about solving the first case. Now generalize...you can solve the third case by turning it into the form of second.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't here to provide code for homework solutions, so you give it a try, show your attempts even for the first easier case. In that way you will get most help from this community

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by building each row in the triangle. First write a function that takes you from one row to the next row up

```py
def next_row(row):
    return [row[i] + row[i+1] for i in range(len(row) - 1)
```

Now if you are given a row, you can check whether there is only one element in the row and return that element or if there is more than one element you find the next row and return the pyramid value of that row.

```py
def pyramid(row):
    if len(row) == 1:
        return row[0]
    else:
        return pyramid(next_row(row))
```

Or you could do some math first and determine how many times each number in the starting row will be added to make the last row. This is not a trivial calculation. But if you draw it out you might see it. The number of times the element in the nth position of the row will be summed into the final answer is the value of the nth position of the row of pascal's triangle with the number of elements of your input row.

That is to say, you should dot product your input row with the row of pascal's triangle of the same length. You can construct the correct row of pascal's triangle directly. As of python 3.8 you can `from math import comb` in case you don't have python 3.8, I'll implement it here

```py
from math import factorial

def comb(n, r):
    return factorial(n) / (factorial(r) * factorial(n-r))
```

Then the nth row of pascal's triangle can be computed:

```py
def pascals_row(n):
    return [comb(n-1, i) for i in range(0, n)]
```

And we can now directly compute pyramid from a starting row

```py
def dot_product(a, b):
    zipped = zip(a, b)
    return sum(z[0] * z[1] for z in zipped)

def pyramid(row):
    return dot_product(row, pascals_row(len(row)))
```

And you can check that both versions of pyramid give the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to give you the actual code :), but since I solved it anyway, here it is. Solved it using recursion-

```
def pyramid(thislist):
    if(len(thislist) == 1):
        print(thislist[0])
        return
    newlist = []
    
    for i in range(len(thislist)-1):
        newlist.append(thislist[i] + thislist[i+1])
        
    pyramid(newlist)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    mylist = [3, 2, 1]
    pyramid(mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is the easiest way to approach it:

```
def pyramid(A):
    return A[0] if len(A)==1 else pyramid([a+b for a,b in zip(A,A[1:])])

pyramid([1,2,3]) # 8
```

But you can also do it iteratively

```
def pyramid(A):
    while len(A)>1:
        A = [a+b for a,b in zip(A,A[1:])]
    return A[0]
```

The trick is to use zip() to obtain the pair of numbers to add up (each number with the next one in the list)